# fatal: ls-files -i must be used with either -o or -c with Git 2.32.0

Tags: git

Using Git 2.32.0, I'm getting an error when I run the following command to list files that are excluded by a rule in .gitignore, but committed to the repository:

```
$ git ls-files -i --exclude-standard
fatal: ls-files -i must be used with either -o or -c
```

The same command works fine with Git 2.31.1 (and below)

Is this expected? It seems odd a command that has worked forever would break in a minor version update. The help page also still lists `-c` as the default, so I'm wondering if I now have to always also add `-c` to the command?

Comment: Confirmed that this command is fine in 2.30.1.

Comment: Seems odd that they'd break the "no behavioral changes" promise for this.

Comment: "No breaking changes to the behavior of plumbing commands" is one of Git's stronger guarantees. Whatever process led to accepting `b338e9` is broken on several fundamental levels.

Comment: Thanks @jthill for digging into the code and finding the commit 

Comment: The release note says: "git clean" and "git ls-files -i" had confusion around working on or showing ignored paths inside an ignored directory, which has been corrected (merge b548f0f156 en/dir-traversal later to maint). That might be relevant.

Comment: The evidence offered in support of that assertion is a single anecdote. I've been using Git for longer than I've been on SO, and I've been here nine years. First time anyone in my memory got tripped up by that. Lots of confusion about `-cx`, that doesn't work without `-i`, you have to `-cix` and invert the exclusons. None about the bare `-i` that I can recall or find.

Comment: For posterity, the commit that introduced the change is https://github.com/git/git/commit/b338e9f668737e08201c990450b8c3d744f63162 (identified by @jthill)